# Error of 'list not defined' while appending to the same declared list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have defined a function in which i am appending to an empty list.
Code for the same is attached below.
But when i call for that list in my next function, the error says:
name 'train_set_sizes' is not defined

My code is:

```
test_percent=0.3 # as an example
batch_size = 10 # as an example

def get_LSTM_train_size(datain, batch_size, test_percent):
   
    number_of_samples = datain.shape[0]
    print("# Shape of the input dataframe",number_of_samples)
    number_of_samples *= 1 - test_percent
    
    train_set_sizes = []
    
    for size in range(int(number_of_samples) - 100,int(number_of_samples)): 
        mod=size%batch_size
        if (mod == 0):
            train_set_sizes.append([size])
            print(size)
    return train_set_sizes, max(train_set_sizes)
```

Comment: Do you have the `train_set_sizes` list declared?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: Can you share your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

The `list.append()` function works on an existing list.

You can declare an empty list before calling that function.

```
train_set_sizes = []
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did create an empty list too. I'l edit my original question as well. Still I get the same error, despite declaring an empty list.

Comment: Please give the full code. And the full error as well. We need to know exactly where the error is happening

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the list in current function, thus you can not use it in another, unless you make it global, or return the whole list.
P.S. It would be easier to help, if you share the complete code.